# Update a Themeroller-based theme

Tags: jquery, themeroller

I have a jQueryUI theme built by Themeroller (1.7.2) that i'd like to tweak via Themeroller. I recall seeing there was a method to use an existing custom theme as a starting point for a new theme - essentially importing the old theme so additional tweaks could be executed.

Can't see instructions on how to do that now.

thx

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From: [rdworth](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/import-a-themeroller-based-package-back-to-themeroller-for-further-tweaking)

The url for your custom theme is inside the theme css file. Put it in your web browser and it will re-create your custom theme on ThemeRoller again, allowing you to further customize it.